# How to use USGS Bulk Download on EC2 linux Server?

Tags: raster, linux, download, amazon-ec2, landsat-8

I am interesting in downloading Landsat 8 rasters to an Amazon EC2 instance and would like to know how to do it.

I already install USGS Bulk Download but I do not know how to use it in terminal mode (so far I only use the Windows 7 version with the Graphic User Interface).

Comment: Landsat 8 data is available for anyone to use via Amazon S3.
You should try it. https://aws.amazon.com/public-data-sets/landsat/